# nginx works fine but php7.2-fpm does not works fine

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to run php7.2-fpm with nginx on ubuntu 18.04 to run Wordpress. Nginx works fine, but php does not work.

log file:

```
2020/08/10 11:06:34 [error] 107906#107906: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/htmlunix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ###.###.###.###, server: example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2020/08/10 11:09:57 [error] 108481#108481: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ###.###.###.###, server: example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2020/08/10 11:20:13 [error] 109596#109596: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ###.###.###.###, server: example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2020/08/10 11:22:35 [error] 110539#110539: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ###.###.###.###, server: example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2020/08/10 11:22:36 [error] 110539#110539: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ###.###.###.###, server: example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2020/08/10 11:26:10 [error] 110817#110817: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ###.###.###.###, server: example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2020/08/10 11:27:05 [error] 110926#110926: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ###.###.###.###, server: example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2020/08/10 11:30:43 [error] 110926#110926: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ###.###.###.###, server: example.com, request: "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2020/08/10 11:38:20 [error] 111593#111593: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ###.###.###.###, server: example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

my nginx config file:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    charset UTF-8;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files            $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_pass         unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index        index.php;
        include              fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
    
    location / {
        root  /data/web;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

sorry my short english.

Comment: And php7.2-fpm.sock exists on /run/php

Comment: Your error said webserver can't find the file to show for 404 error "not found". So first you need to understand why `index.php` is'nt found. Did you check `/data/web` folder - is it contain `index.php` in the root of that folder?

Comment: index.php exists. and I tried phpinfo.php, which also exists on my web root folder. But, html pages works fine, but php pages does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misconfiguration in `nginx` config file.

First of all, you specify `root` and `index` directives inside `location \` sections.

```
location / {
        root  /data/web;
        index index.html index.htm;
}
```

That section will only work when all other sections didn't match, because it has the shortes mask length (`/` is one symbol)

Every `URL` ending with `.php`, like `phpinfo.php` or `index.php` will match to `location ~ \.php$` section:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files            $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_pass         unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index        index.php;
        include              fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

But - there is no `root` and `index` directives (btw `index` is optional, but first is mandatory in your case).

There is two solutions:

First, specify `root` and `index` directives inside `location ~ \.php$` section:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files            $uri = 404;
        root                 /data/web;
        index                index.php index.html index.htm;
        fastcgi_pass         unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param        SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index        index.php;
        include              fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

The second one is to put `root` and `index` in global context (inside `server`):

```
server {

    listen 80;
    charset UTF-8;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root  /data/web;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ...

}
```

UPD: Also `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;` directive must be added after the `fastcgi_pass`

I highly recommend you to read [Official nginx.org "Begginers guide"](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) to better understand how things works.

Comment: and I missed this line: fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;. So I got empty respond. After I add this line, it works great.

Comment: Alright, thanks for feedback! I've updated the answer.